# The page does not appear when I press the URL in the Rails password reset email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

## Assumption

We are building a service using Rails and Nuxt.js. We have sent a password reset email from Rails, but when the reset URL is clicked, it does not go to the desired page. How can I configure the email sent to the user so that it goes to the desired page? By the way, the URL also has a token for password reset.

## What we want to achieve

I want to go from the password reset email to the password reset page.

## Code

mail

```rb
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>
  Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through
  the link below.
</p>
# I want to go to　http://localhost:8080/user/edit/newPassword
# but I go to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url&reset_password_token=token
<p>
<%= link_to 'Change my password', "http://localhost:8080/user/edit/password?token=#{@token}"%> 
</p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>
  Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new
  one.
</p>
```

Comment: You're using ActionMailer here? If so, make a an URL regarding your actual URL or use `localhost:8000` if it's the URL where your Nuxt app is. Then, in Nuxt, catch the path `/user/edit/password` and the query with `$route.query.token`. There, you will be able to reset the whole thing with the new password + the token by sending it back to the backend.

Comment: @kissu  I'm using ``:recoverable`` from devise instead of ActionMailer for email, so I'm putting ``localhost:8000`` in the URL of the email I'm sending from Rails, setting ``/user/edit/newPassword`` on the Nuxt side, and then using ``$route. query.token``. to get a token for password reset?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: @kissu I noticed that the email changes were not reflected in the first place. I may have misconfigured...